# INSERTAR SUMA DE VALORES A OTRA TABLA

Tags: mysql, tablas

necesito ayuda por favor, 
tengo tres tablas con los siguientes valores (Usuarios, Resultado, Preguntas):

usuarios contiene las columnas :

1. idusuarios
2. nombre
3. password
4. email
5. puntos

resultados contiene:

1. idresultados
2. idusuarios
3. idpreguntas
4. puntos

preguntas contiene:

1. idpreguntas
2. pregunta
3. res1
4. res2
5. res3
6. res4

con el siguiente codigo hago la consulta que necesito pero no incorpora el resultado en la tabla usuarios sino que me genera una tabla aparte, que luego se borra

```
SELECT a.idusuarios, a.nombre, SUM(b.puntos)
FROM usuarios a LEFT JOIN resultados b ON a.idusuarios = b.idusuarios 
GROUP BY a.idusuarios, a.nombre
```

La pregunta es:

> Como se puede hacer para que se sumen los puntos de la tabla resultado por cada idusuario y el resultado de dicha suma se guarde en la tabla Usuarios en la columna puntos, (en este momento aparece como NULL).

Espero me puedan dar una mano. gracias.

Comment: ¿en tu tabla de resultados solo tienes resultados de 1 prueba o de varias?

Comment: Como sugerencia, la información se pone como texto para que la gente pueda replicar tu problema más fácil, para que lo puedan leer desde el móvil y para que las personas con discapacidad te puedan leer y ayudar más fácil. Además, evita usar mayúscula sostenida; no te van a ayudar más rápido por ello.

Comment: Así mismo, las preguntas del tipo: "Tengo que hacer esto" sin mostrar el código que has escrito no suelen ser bien recibidas ya que la respuesta será siempre adivinando y no encaja en el formato de preguntas y respuestas del sitio. 
Recomiendo que hagas el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender el funcionamiento de SO y ya de paso ganar tu primera medalla. 
Por otro lado, estaría bien que le echaras un vistazo a [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tus preguntas reciban respuesta cuanto antes.

Comment: @JosueArriola si señor, solo de una prueba, la cual para el ejemplo tiene cinco preguntas.

Comment: @Alfabravo acabo de recibir tu comentario referente a la formulacion de la pregunta, e hice las correcciones. Gracias.

Comment: @Alfabravo referente a tu segundo comentario, no muestro el codigo porque espero entiendas no lo se, y aun no tengo ningun codigo, lo unico que pude encontrar referente al tema es el codigo que adicione en la edicion de la pregunta despues de tu comentario inicial., el cual me arroja una consulta de lo que quiero hacer. gracias.

Answer (score 1):

Espero no adelantarme con la respuesta pero, si ya tienes la tabla usuarios y en la tabla resultados solamente tienes datos de una prueba y no de muchas lo que debes hacer es un update, seria algo asi:

```
update usuarios a
inner join (select idusuarios,sum(puntos) puntos from resultados group by idusuarios) b on a.idusuarios = b.idusuarios
set a.puntos = b.puntos;
```

Yo hice la prueba con estos datos

```
insert into usuarios values (1,'usuario_1','xxx','usuario_1@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (2,'usuario_2','xxx','usuario_2@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (3,'usuario_3','xxx','usuario_3@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (4,'usuario_4','xxx','usuario_4@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (5,'usuario_5','xxx','usuario_5@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (6,'usuario_6','xxx','usuario_6@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (7,'usuario_7','xxx','usuario_7@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (8,'usuario_8','xxx','usuario_8@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (9,'usuario_9','xxx','usuario_9@email.com',null);
insert into usuarios values (10,'usuario_10','xxx','usuario_10@email.com',null);

insert into resultados values (1,'1','6','1');
insert into resultados values (2,'1','2','1');
insert into resultados values (3,'1','3','1');
insert into resultados values (4,'1','4','1');
insert into resultados values (5,'1','5','1');
insert into resultados values (6,'2','1','1');
insert into resultados values (7,'2','2','0');
insert into resultados values (8,'2','3','1');
insert into resultados values (9,'2','4','0');
insert into resultados values (10,'2','5','1');
```

Y el resultado fue este ya que solo le asigne puntos al id 1 y 2:

```
+------------+------------+----------+----------------------+--------+
| idusuarios | nombre     | password | email                | puntos |
+------------+------------+----------+----------------------+--------+
|          1 | usuario_1  | xxx      | usuario_1@email.com  |      5 |
|          2 | usuario_2  | xxx      | usuario_2@email.com  |      3 |
|          3 | usuario_3  | xxx      | usuario_3@email.com  |   NULL |
|          4 | usuario_4  | xxx      | usuario_4@email.com  |   NULL |
|          5 | usuario_5  | xxx      | usuario_5@email.com  |   NULL |
|          6 | usuario_6  | xxx      | usuario_6@email.com  |   NULL |
|          7 | usuario_7  | xxx      | usuario_7@email.com  |   NULL |
|          8 | usuario_8  | xxx      | usuario_8@email.com  |   NULL |
|          9 | usuario_9  | xxx      | usuario_9@email.com  |   NULL |
|         10 | usuario_10 | xxx      | usuario_10@email.com |   NULL |
+------------+------------+----------+----------------------+--------+
```